# Returning only values that match two condition filter

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to return only values that match a 2 condition filter. The problem I am having is that some names have more than 1 code and some names only have 1.

```
name <- c("Jeff", "Jeff", "Jill", "Jill", "Angie")
total <- c(123, 234, 345, 456, 567)
code <- c("abc", "xyz", "abc", "xyz", "abc")

table <- data.frame(name, total, code)
```

Full table

```
name  total code
Jeff  123   abc
Jeff  234   xyz
Jill  345   abc
Jill  456   xyz
Angie 567   xyz
```

The output I am looking for is

```
name  total code
Jeff  123   abc
Jeff  234   xyz
Jill  345   abc
Jill  456   xyz
```

I have tried
This did not work because it returns everything expected

```
library(dplyr)

test1 <- filter(table, code == "xyz" | code == "abc")
```

I thought maybe an %>% would work but this gives me the same thing as OR filter.

```
target <- c("xyz", "abc")
test2 <- filter(table, code %in% target)
```

I cant use a "AND" because it is in the same column.

```
test2 <- filter(table, code == "xyz" & code == "abc")
```

Comment: Ok running the below answers on my code that is much more elaborate I am getting an output that is not exactly what I was expecting. Do I ask a new question using the answers below or fix this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would phrase your goal as *"Select all names that have both `xyz` and `abc` in their code column."* The main problem with your attempts is that you've done nothing to indicate that the need to do this *by name* - you only reference the `code` column. We need to use `group_by(name)` for this:

```
table %>% group_by(name) %>% 
    filter("abc" %in% code & "xyz" %in% code)
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
# # Groups:   name [2]
#     name total   code
#   <fctr> <dbl> <fctr>
# 1   Jeff   123    abc
# 2   Jeff   234    xyz
# 3   Jill   345    abc
# 4   Jill   456    xyz
```

We also need to use `%in%` rather than `==` because we want to check that each pattern exists *somewhere* in the code column. `==` will try to only select the individual rows with that pattern, which as you point out will result in no rows with an `&` condition, because `code` can't be both `abc` and `xyz` at the same time. (Flo.P's use of `any` plays the same role as my use of `%in%`.)

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```r
library(dplyr)
name <- c("Jeff", "Jeff", "Jill", "Jill", "Angie")
total <- c(123, 234, 345, 456, 567)
code <- c("abc", "xyz", "abc", "xyz", "abc")

table <- data.frame(name, total, code)

table %>% 
  group_by(name) %>%
  filter(any(code == "xyz") & any(code =="abc" ))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#> # Groups: name [2]
#>   name  total code 
#>   <fct> <dbl> <fct>
#> 1 Jeff    123 abc  
#> 2 Jeff    234 xyz  
#> 3 Jill    345 abc  
#> 4 Jill    456 xyz
```

Comment: I've never used "any" with a filter I will remember this one.

Comment: Another way of writing it is `all(c("abc", "xyz") %in% code)`. Btw you can use `&&` instead of `&` since `any` returns a length-one value. This "short-circuits" computation of `x && y` when x is false.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use two %in% and a "and".  Here is some sample code:

```
target_name = c("Jeff", "Jill")
target_code = c("abc", "xyz")

table %>%
     filter( name %in% target_name & code %in% target_code)
```

The output is example what you want:

```
> table %>%
+   filter( name %in% target_name & code %in% target_code)
    name total code
    1 Jeff   123  abc
    2 Jeff   234  xyz
    3 Jill   345  abc
    4 Jill   456  xyz
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The point is to not define the names. If you know the names then what is the point of the code...

Comment: Hmm yeah works for this small table but what about a table where there are n names?

Comment: So what exactly the 2 condition filter means?

Comment: @Jeffkrop, do you have the target names?  This will change the whole stofy?